# Why do Jehovah's Witnesses travel in pairs?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, great-commission

Why do Jehovah's Witnesses travel in pairs instead of a group and go proselytizing door-to-door? What is the typical arrangement (friend and friend, sister and sister, brother and brother, husband and wife, etc.)? Are these people paid by the Watchtower to minister?

Comment: I thought I've seen them proselyte in neighborhoods in groups... though perhaps their actual door approaches are in pairs or as individuals. Anyway, this is a valid question. +1

Comment: Yeah - they come in packs, not pairs.  I gave a more general answer in the Mormon question, but I think JW practice may have some unique properties.

Comment: @AffableGeek I'm positive they come in pairs, not packs.

Comment: @anonymous - nope, they come in packs. The pack splits into pairs. These are rotational territories carefully documented to know for sure if each door has been given the chance to hear the word of God. As for the pairing, it is not specific exactly (brother brother, husband wife, etc) they congregate every morning and group according to whoever showed for field service. None of which are paid by the Watchtower. All congregation finances are discussed openly at their financial meeting, usually paired with the theocratic ministerial school. JW does not really stockpile money, per say.

Comment: I'd separate off the _"Are these people paid by the Watchtower to minister?"_ question to a separate question. The short answer is _No_, but that can be elaborated on.

Comment: They travel in more than pairs to coffee shops though :D

Answer (score 3):

> [Mark 6:7 (NWT)](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/mark/6/)
>   Now he summoned the twelve, and he initiated sending them out two by two, and he began to give them authority over the unclean spirits.
>
> [Luke 10:1 (NWT)](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/luke/10/)
>   After these things the Lord designated seventy others and sent them forth by twos in advance of him into every city and place to which he himself was going to come.

Jesus did this

1. so we would have someone to work with, and
2. for consideration for the householder, so a large group of people don't show up at their door among other reasons.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a good first post. Thank you for quoting the Scripture, which the JW's undoubtedly use to support insistence on this practice. However, I suggest linking to something on jw.org to substantiate what you have said. As it is now, we just have to take your word for it that this is what a JW would say. I also made formatting edits to your post. [Click edit](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/25572/edit) to see how to do that correctly. I linked to NIV, but I assume you used NWT.

Comment: That's pretty much what a JW would say. I was one for years. Points 1 and 2 would vary though. There are more scriptures that would be used to back it. Typically about good association and being support for one another.

Comment: For coffee, its groups of 5's and 6's. You should add that :D

Comment: Although working in pairs is not mandatory. it is common practice, people can work individually to cover the area more quickly if wanted, or in the case of odd numbers, to make use of time more wisely, but safety is the primary concern when this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Jehovah's Witnesses do not travel in any specific group size. They may travel individually, in cars of four, or even in a minivan full of passengers. Typically though, when preaching in their door to door ministry, Jehovah's Witnesses will send two people to a door. That number may be more if parents are bringing along minor children. In some cases, a single Jehovah's Witness will preach by themselves if they don't have a companion to accompany them.

The most common practice is two Witnesses per door, and this is well established in their organizational directions. The [Our Kingdom Ministry-2001](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/202001282) states:

> One of the foremost benefits is the way our brothers strengthen and support us in the public ministry. Jesus sent his disciples “two by two” to preach. (Mark 6:7; Luke 10:1) In line with this pattern, when we work with others in the field service, we experience the truthfulness of Ecclesiastes 4:9, 10. As we carry out our ministry together, the faith, obedience, and love of our companions infuse us with courage and renew our zeal.

This direction cites scriptural precedent as the basis for preaching in pairs, in harmony with Jesus' instructions to his apostles or disciples when commissioning them to preach. The scriptural principle in Ecclesiastes 4:9, 10a says: "Two are better than one because they have a good reward for their hard work. For if one of them falls, the other can help his partner up."

There are specific ways that Jehovah's Witnesses are taught to "strengthen and support" each other when engaging in their ministry. [The Watchtower—Study Edition January 2009](https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/w20090115/Find-Joy-in-the-Disciple-Making-Work/) makes this suggestion:

> Furthermore, Jesus sent workers out to preach in pairs. (Luke 10:1) Therefore, if you find it a challenge to conduct a Bible study, pray for God’s spirit to give you wisdom and then team up with a preaching companion who can give you confidence and whose experience may be of help to you.

An article in the [Our Kingdom Ministry—2014](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/202014122) entitled "Improving Our Skills in the Ministry​—Being a Helpful Companion" points out that a preaching partner "can provide needed support if his fellow publisher encounters a difficult situation or is unsure of how to answer a householder." [The Enjoy Life Forever!—An Interactive Bible Course](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1102021222#h=12:0-13:392) notes that "Preaching together also brought much joy to the disciples. (Luke 10:17)"

As a secondary reason, Jehovah's Witnesses may also preach in pairs for safety reasons. This has been suggested in the [Our Kingdom Ministry—1996](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/201996241#h=6) which states:

> Be Cautious and Discreet: Going out at dusk or after dark could be hazardous in certain areas. It would be wise to travel in pairs or groups on well-lit streets and visit homes or apartment buildings only where there is some assurance that you will be safe.

Comment: Please be aware that the use of italics makes it difficult reading for users with dyslexia and other visual impairments. (See [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/how-do-i-write-an-accessible-stack-exchange-post))